# Eclipse Content Assist Takes Focus and doesn't let me type

Tags: java, eclipse

The Eclipse Content Assist takes the focus and doesn't let me type. I even tried reinstalling and updating. I restore default settings in preferences. Here is a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C_oerIFj_AF-NY4Vp3pYD8PgKzlAJukx/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you reproduce this with the current Eclipse version without additional plugins, especially with no plugin from Genuitec?

Comment: Yes. I tried it with no plugins. A fresh Install.

Comment: If you really still get this without the Genuitec plugins shown in your video in the current Eclipse version and a fresh workspace, it could be caused by a monitor/display tool or another Windows 10 tool,  but probably not by Eclipse. Otherwise, it would be reproducible and there would be bug reports.

Comment: Hmmm Alright. I was suspecting that it was something related to Windows 10. Thank you so Much!

Comment: Yes! I fixed it! To those coming from elsewhere, here's the link: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3vbzth/turn_off_focus_stealing/

 In Regedit (Start button+R, then type regedit), the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimeout. Change the value to 0

Comment: Nvm It broken again :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is almost 3 years old but the issue has been annoying me for past few months and I finally found a workaround.

If you run Eclipse "as admin" I found the issue doesn't happen anymore. That doesn't resolve why it is happening, but it is a workaround.